# Limiting Response Frequency of Event While Ensuring Last Even is Responded To

Tags: javascript, jquery

As an example, I have some sliders and other controls in the Ui.  When control values change, I trigger an event to update the corresponding values in the model.  At some point I then send requests to the server to notify of the changes.

I need to figure out the best way to set a limit on the frequency that I send these requests to the server, and also only make these requests when something has changed.  And make sure that the last message to the server represents the last change made to the model.

I think I can make my own implementation, but I wanted to get advice because I suppose this problem already has an elegant solution.

Comment: You could try throttling the requests.

Comment: There are well working `throttle` functions on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the pseudocode that comes to mind.

1) When a change is made, you add it to an array of changes, and you start a timer counting (if it isn't counting already).

2) When the timer reaches a preset time (like every 5 seconds, or 30 seconds, or whatever you want), you push the array of changes to the server, clear out the array, and stop the timer from counting.

3) If the user clicks a button to leave the page, you also trigger step 2.

I think that covers everything! (But it doesn't mention the word "throttle" once. I guess I'm an old-school, come-up-with-my-own-solution kind of coder.)

Comment: Thanks for marking this as the answer! I'm pretty happy with my pseudocode. It's simple and robust. :)

Answer (score 0):

The underscore library has a method called throttle which does exactly what you want: http://underscorejs.org/#throttle